# Characteristic Class exercises

Tags: reference-request, algebraic-topology, characteristic-classes

I tagged this as "homework" because my supervisor told me I need to be better at computing characteristic classes.

The classic examples I can think of are tangent bundles and tautological line bundles.  I'm wondering if people can suggest some illustrative problems to solve, computing characteristic classes of fibre bundles.

Comment: have you looked at the problems in Milnor and Stashef?

Comment: Some of them yes, that's where I'm learning the basics.  Do you know any good examples that aren't emphasized in this book?

Comment: You can look through the chap IV, characteristic classes of *Differential forms in Algebraic topology* by R. Bott and L. W. Tu